# I want an alert box after form submit not redirect to thank-you.html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am wanting say thanks in an alert box instead of redirecting to `thank-you.html`

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact']$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if (empty($name) || empty($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if (IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'tom@amazing-designs.com'; //<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n" . "Here is the message:\n $message" .

$to = "tom@amazing-designs.com"; //<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');
```

I do not want to redirect page to `thank-you.html`. I only want to show the alert with "thanks".

Comment: You are probably looking for ajax to make the post request while staying on the original page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove header('Location: thank-you.html'); and add javascript

```
<script>
    alert('Thank you!!!');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `header()` part with:
`printf("<script> alert('Thank You!'); </script>");`

Comment: thanks showtime but i want to redirect after alert box conformation please what code i have to add in that after printf("<script> alert('Thank You!'); </script>"); please help me as soon as possible